# ShouldPerformSegue in iOS and macOS

Tags: ios, swift, macos

I want to make a segue only if there is some condition. For instance that there is text in a textField.

First I make the connection in storyboard from the icon of the View Controller to the Second View Controller. Then I have the button in ViewController.

In iOS this works well and only makes the segue when there is text in textField1:

```
 @IBAction func goTo2(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let str: String? = textField1.text
        if str!.isEmpty {
            print ("text field is empty. Do not do the segue")
        }
        else {
            print ("Do the segue")
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueTo2", sender: self)
        }
}
```

In macOS, if I do the same, it always makes the segue, also when there is no text in textFiel1. So I have to add shouldPerformSegue.

In macOS this works well:

```
@IBAction func goTo2(_ sender: Any) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueTo2", sender: self)
}

override func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, sender: Any?) -> Bool {     
    let str: String? = textField1.stringValue
    if str!.isEmpty {
        print ("it is empty")
        return false
    }
    else {
        return true
    }     
}
```

In Apple documentation, they say that shouldPerformSegue is for iOS and mac.

What I have described works well but I do not understand why the differences between iOS and maOS. Is that the best way to do it? can anyone explain why?

Comment: You're programmatically doing a segue in the iOS version, whereas in the MacOS version you're using `shouldPerformSegue` In iOS there also exists `shouldPerformSegue`. The way you're handling per OS is different, either method works on either system.

Comment: As already mentioned in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61615376/shouldperformsegue-in-ios-and-macos) it actually makes no sense (in both macOS and iOS) to override the method when you are going to perform the segue *manually* regardless of the different behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two ways to check if you should segue based on your code.

#### Segue Method #1 (iOS & MacOS)

```
@IBAction func goTo2(_ sender: UIButton) {   
        if !textField1.text.isEmpty {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueTo2", sender: self)   
        }
        print ("text field is empty. Do not do the segue")
}
```

#### Segue Method #2 (iOS & MacOS)

```
@IBAction func goTo2(_ sender: Any) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueTo2", sender: self)
}

override func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, sender: Any?) -> Bool {     
    if !textField1.stringValue.isEmpty {
        return true
    }
    print ("it is empty")
    return false  
}
```

As you can see, both `Method #1` and `Method #2` appear to do the same thing but they don't. In `Method #1` you're checking if it's empty BEFORE doing a segue. In `Method #2` you're checking if you should segue AFTER calling a segue.

Either method works, and there are a ton of workarounds. The biggest difference is doing `Method #1` forces you to miss certain opportunities to run other methods such as `prepareForSegue(...)` which means you might miss a lifecycle event. However, you can still use `prepareForSegue(...)` it's just that you can't use is prior to the segue being triggered.

In short, for your uses, based on the current code, it makes no sense to use `Method #2` at all. If however, you needed to perform some function AFTER segue but AND still stop a segue from happening if some condition isn't met, then you'd use `Method #2`, but even that could have a workaround.